# Image decoding (thumbnails) and using data binding

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am downloading a bunch of images and displaying them inside a listbox via data binding.
i.e

```
...
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" Height="90" Width="90" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
...
```

I want to have thumbnails of images. Despite setting the image control to 90x90, images still get decoded at their full original size thus they take up much more memory than they should.

There's a PictureDecoder class that could be used for this purpose, but by the looks of it, it can't be used on a background thread.

I tried creating an attached dependency property which uses a ThreadPool and a WriteableBitmap:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DecodingSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
DecodingSourcePropertyName,
typeof (Uri),
typeof (Image),
new PropertyMetadata(null, OnDecodingSourcePropertyChanged));

static void OnDecodingSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    var img = d as Image;
    double height = img.Height;
    double width = img.Width;
    var uri = (Uri)e.NewValue;
    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)width, (int)height);

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback => {
        var web = new WebClient();
        web.OpenReadCompleted += (sender, evt) => {
            bmp.LoadJpeg(evt.Result);
            evt.Result.Dispose();
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.
            BeginInvoke(() = > {
                img.Source = bmp;
            });
        };
        web.OpenReadAsync(uri);
    }
    });
}

<Image helpers:ImageExt.DecodingSource="{Binding ImageUrl}" Height="90" Width="90" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

but it doesn't respect the stretching property I set.

I am wondering are there any third party controls that could serve a similar purpose?

I would want to avoid having to resize images on a server - eventhough it seems to be the easiest way to do.

Comment: Not really answering your question, but if you resize the pictures on client side you'll have first to load the full-sized version in memory. So handling the resizing on server-side is easier AND reduces memory footprint.

Comment: A valid point. I guess I will probably end up with a server :/. Wanted to avoid it since I will need to maintain one. Still, perhaps there's hope with some Isolated storage caching of converted images, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8 there are new properties in the BitmapImage class - DecodePixelWidth and DecodePixelHeight

```
<Image>
   <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Url"}  DecodePixelWidth="200" DecodePixelHeight="200" />
</Image>
```

It will decode the image to the specified resolution decreasing memory usage. (If you want to maintain aspect ratio just use one of the properties instead of two).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `Image.GetThumbnailImage`?

If the Image contains an embedded thumbnail image, this method retrieves the embedded thumbnail and scales it to the requested size. If the Image does not contain an embedded thumbnail image, this method creates a thumbnail image by scaling the main image.

[Image.GetThumbnailImage Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434150.aspx)

Comment: Hi, looks like this is not available on the windows phone runtime.

Comment: It is available. Just fixed the url in my answer to the wp7 version. Make sure you reference <code>Microsoft.Xna.Framework</code> in your project.

Comment: Seems like it can't be used the way I am using the image control. It assumes you deal with a 'Picture' class, which you obtain by taking a picture through the phone's camera. In my case I have a bunch of Url's, that I load onto the Image control.